# Java Slider - trigger fireStateChanged() without changing the value?

Tags: java, swing, event-handling, jslider, changelistener

I used the code below when initialising my sliders:

```
//Gets the corresponding slider value, from it's represented value. 
int curr = valueToSlider(min, max, current, scale, q, grains); 

final JSlider slider = new JSlider(JSlider.VERTICAL, 0, grains, curr);

slider.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {

  public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent event) {
    double value = sliderToValue(min, max, slider.getValue(), scale, q, grains); 
    String str = ""; 

    if (valueType == SliderValueType.FLOAT) 
       str = String.format("%.2f",value);
    if (valueType == SliderValueType.INTEGER) 
       str = String.format("%.0f", value); 

    valueLabel.setText(str); 
    callCommand(c, value);
  }
});
```

Now I need to trigger the changed event to get that valueLabel label to set in its correct format.

```
slider.setValue(curr);
```

That doesn't trigger the changed event, I'm guessing because the value hasn't changed. A simple hacky fix is to just do something like:

```
slider.setValue(1);
slider.setValue(curr);
```

But you could imagine that in some code, that triggering the changed event with a random value, might have unwanted consequences.

I could reproduce that `setText` method in my initialisation method.

```
if (valueType == SliderValueType.FLOAT) 
   str = String.format("%.2f",curr);

if (valueType == SliderValueType.INTEGER) 
   str = String.format("%.0f", curr); 

valueLabel.setText(str);
```

(Which sounds like the best solution here to be honest).

But just wondering - is there a way to trigger an changed event another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refactor the contents of `stateChanged()` into a separate method, say `updateLabel()`. Call that method from both the `stateChanged()` method and your initialisation code.

I agree, it would be wrong to set the value to some arbitrary value just to trigger a change.

Note: you can manually trigger a change through `JSlider.fireStateChanged()`, however that's still less clear to a future code maintainer than simply calling `updateLabel()`.

Comment: Call me finicky, but you can't create a method inside a method straight forward like, in java. 

I can do the [runnable trick](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t373066-why-i-cannot-have-a-method-inside-another-method.html). Which would be useful - but just looks more confusing than 3 lines of repeated code. 

Or I could create a private method outside this method, and pass in the label and the value, but I feel icky about that - code clutter?

Comment: @user1068446 who said anything about a method-in-a-method? Binding between slider value and label text (that's basically what you are doing) belongs _somewhere_ - that place can be a single listener (your ChangeListener) only in the most simplistic contexts, which even yours isn't (you need it twice). So it must be moved to where it is accessible from all collaborators which need it, f.i. as a method of the view class (for simple contexts). Next step is to extract some kind of business model which has-a value and bind both label and slider to that value.

Comment: @mKorbel thanks, but then I would need to add some code snippets ... which currently isn't attractive :-)